# Elegant way to define new random generation functions with vector parameters

Tags: r

I'd like to define new random generation functions in **R**, e.g. combination of the `rbinom()` function with a point weight on zero. Parameters can be vectors with length higher than one and should work like in the common functions, e.g. `rnorm()`. I have some implementation but probably there are better, faster and more elegant ways to do that. Any help is appreciated!

R version: 4.0.4

Example 1: concatenation of point zero and binomial distribution

```
# p0 ... probability for point zero
# m, p1 ... common parameters of function rbinom()

r0binom <- function(n, p0, m, p1) {
    len <- ceiling(n/length(p0))
    rfirst <- as.vector(t(sapply(p0, function(p) sample(0:1, len, TRUE, c(p, 1-p)))))
    ifelse(rfirst[1:n] == 0, 0, rbinom(n, m, p1))
}

set.seed(1); r0binom(10, c(0.3, 0.6), c(1, 12), c(0.6, 0.4))
# [1] 1 3 0 4 0 5 0 9 1 0
```

Example 2: concatenation of point zero and discrete uniform distribution

```
# p0 ... probability for point zero
# m1, m2 ... start and end point of uniform range

r0dunif <- function(n, p0, m1, m2) {
    len <- ceiling(n/length(p0))
    k <- m2 - m1 + 1
    res <- apply(cbind(p0, m1, m2, k), 1,
                 function(x) sample(c(0, x[2]:x[3]),
                                    size = len,
                                    replace = TRUE,
                                    prob = c(x[1], rep((1-x[1])/x[4], x[4]))))
    as.vector(t(res))[1:n]
}

set.seed(1); r0dunif(10, c(0.2, 0.4), c(1, 1), c(5, 5))
# [1] 2 1 3 1 4 4 1 3 2 0
```

**Addition** I'd like to add a third example for which I'm still searching:

Example 3: concatenation of point zero and right truncated discrete linear decreasing distribution

```
# p0 ... probability for point zero
# m1, m2 ... start and end point of decreasing range

r0drtlindecr <- function(n, p0, m1, m2) {
    len <- ceiling(n/length(p0))
    k <- m2 - m1 + 1
    res <- apply(cbind(p0, m1, m2, k), 1,
                 function(x) sample(c(0, x[2]:x[3]),
                                    size = len,
                                    replace = TRUE,
                                    prob = c(x[1], (x[4]:1)/sum(1:x[4])*(1-x[1]))))
    as.vector(t(res))[1:n]
}

set.seed(1); r0drtlindecr(10, c(0.3, 0.6), c(1, 3), c(5, 7))
# [1] 0 5 1 6 2 3 4 3 0 0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of modifications I would suggest.

Firstly, your vector of 1s and 0s can be created much more easily without having to manually create recycling rules if, instead of using `sample`, you use `rbinom`. For example

```r
1 - rbinom(n, 1, p0)
```

will give you a vector of length `n` comprising 1s and 0s sampled with the appropriate probabilities, with the vector recycling rules *already applied*.

Secondly, there is no need for an `ifelse`. If you have a vector of 1s and 0s you can just multiply it with your sample.

That means your first function could just be:

```r
r0binom <- function(n, p0, m, p1) (1 - rbinom(n, 1, p0)) * rbinom(n, m, p1)
```

Resulting in:

```r
set.seed(1)

r0binom(10, c(0.3, 0.6), c(1, 12), c(0.6, 0.4)) 
#> [1] 1 0 0 4 0 5 0 9 1 0
```

Note that this gives a subtly different set of zeros from the version using `sample`

Comment: Very good answer! If I take it for the second example this should work: (1 - rbinom(n, 1, p0)) * round(runif(n, m1, m2), 0)

Comment: @JohnSnider yes, I think that should work